# Multiple table echos not displaying in page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The above code is designed to display info stored in sql table.  everything is corresponding to the titles in the table and in the correct order.  however the page it is from is only displaying the first 2 columns and not the others.  everything looks as if it is in order to me.  is my statement wrong?

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("xxx","y","y","yyyy");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tripdata ");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo $row['trip_id'] . " " . $row['image'] . " " . $row['date'] . " " . $row['destination'] . " " . $row['hl'] . " " . $row['cost'] . " " . $row['blurb'] . " " . $row['whatinc'] . " " . $row['whatopt'] . " " . $row['itin'] . " " . $row['depinfo'] . " " . $row['ppcode']; 
      echo "<br>";
      }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: DONT post you login details on the net!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try using assoc

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  echo $row['trip_id'] . " " . $row['image'] . " " . $row['date'] . " " . $row['destination'] . " " . $row['hl'] . " " . $row['cost'] . " " . $row['blurb'] . " " . $row['whatinc'] . " " . $row['whatopt'] . " " . $row['itin'] . " " . $row['depinfo'] . " " . $row['ppcode']; 
  echo "<br>";
  }
```

i usual use this and no problem

assoc is index name based on field name
but array is based on number (0, 1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Strange. Try do loop instead:

```
do {    
  echo $row['trip_id'] . " " . $row['image'] . " " . $row['date'] . " " . $row['destination'] . " " . $row['hl'] . " " . $row['cost'] . " " . $row['blurb'] . " " . $row['whatinc'] . " " . $row['whatopt'] . " " . $row['itin'] . " " . $row['depinfo'] . " " . $row['ppcode']; 
  echo "<br>";

} while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: sorry mate. I meant it was the first 2 columns and not the rest.  it is really weird

Comment: try: $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); var_dump($row);

Comment: will you see the rest columns?

Comment: its only actually the first column that is being displayed.  it is the primary key

Comment: Did you use var_dump($row) before your loop to see all records in the array? Try Hans's advice : mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array